# Trading between Pokemon Ruby and Sapphire

Tags: game-boy-advance, pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald

I have a regular Gameboy Advance and a Gameboy Advance SP. I also have the games Pokemon Ruby and Sapphire. If I get a GBA link cable can I trade between them even If I have different GBAs? Or do I need two regular GBAs or two GBA SPs?

Answer (score 1):

It works. I've been to local meetings to battle against strangers who had all kinds of GBA models and found no trouble linking with them, so, I'm assuming trading is no different.

Comment: Can verify this works. The difference in GBA models makes no difference; I have traded between my GBA and GBA SP multiple times without issue.